# Wrong MessageDlg icon with DlgType mtConfirmation constant?

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-10.1-berlin

In Delphi 10.1.2 Berlin, in a `Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg` function, the `DlgType` constants `mtInformation` and `mtConfirmation` create the same dialog icon. For example:

```
if Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg('Do you really want to remove the selected item?',  mtConfirmation, mbOKCancel, 0) = mrOk then
begin
  RemoveTheSelectedItem;
end;
```

[image]

```
if Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg('Do you really want to remove the selected item?',  mtInformation, mbOKCancel, 0) = mrOk then
begin
  RemoveTheSelectedItem;
end;
```

[image]

But shouldn't the `DlgType` constant `mtConfirmation` display a **question mark** icon, (as the other `DlgType` constants `mtWarning` and `mtError` create each a different icon)?

How can I get a **question mark** icon with the `DlgType` constant `mtConfirmation`?

Comment: I had exactly this issue today!.. thanks for asking, and thanks to Tom for the answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is said in the [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg):

> Having mtConfirmation Show a Question Mark
>
> Dialog boxes of TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation type show an information
>   icon.
>
> In the past, they used to show a question mark instead, but Microsoft
>   removed the question mark symbol from the Windows API function that
>   the VCL uses to display TMsgDlgType.mtConfirmation dialog boxes.
>   Quoting Microsoft:  "The question-mark message icon is no longer
>   recommended because it does not clearly represent a specific type of
>   message and because the phrasing of a message as a question could
>   apply to any message type. In addition, users can confuse the message
>   symbol question mark with Help information."  To use the previous
>   dialog box appearance, you must set the UseLatestCommonDialogs
>   variable of the Vcl.Dialogs unit to False.

So this code:

```
  Vcl.Dialogs.UseLatestCommonDialogs := False;
  if Vcl.Dialogs.MessageDlg('Do you really want to remove the selected item?',  mtConfirmation, mbOKCancel, 0) = mrOk then
  begin
    RemoveTheSelectedItem;
  end;
```

produces this result:

[image]

Comment: I really can't follow the logic of Microsoft. A symbol's meaning is always defined by its context. Which means: When a control on which I can act upon (e.g. a button) has a question mark symbol then I can use it to get information. But the question mark in the dialog cannot be acted upon and so it gives the dialog the meaning of BEING information.